# Using ggplot to plot a single category data vs the entire dataset with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Dataset looks like this:

```
CarType    SaleYear    TotalNoSales
Ferrari    1991        1343
Ford       1991        32432
Tesla      2017        42343
Ferrari    2001        1234
Tesla      2018        12343
Toyota     1992        1235
....
```

What I want to do I use `ggplot` with `R` to have a `geom_line()` plot that I can use to compare `Ferrari` `TotalNoSales` with rest of the `CarType`

**What did I do?**

This is the code I came up but it only does for one `CarType`, whereas I want another line on the same graph that shows the sum of total sales of other `CarType`

```
cartype_ferrari <- car_dataset %>%
  filter(CarType == "Ferrari") %>%
  group_by(SaleYear, TotalNoSales) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(Count))

ggplot(cartype_ferrari, aes(x = SaleYear, y = n))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab("Year")+ 
  ylab("Total Car Sales")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I do not have your data. If you still have problem, please provide some data.

```
cartype_ferrari <- car_dataset %>%
  mutate(Ferrari = as.numeric(CarType == "Ferrari")) %>%
  group_by(SaleYear, Ferrari) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(TotalNoSales))

ggplot(cartype_ferrari, aes(x = SaleYear, y = n, color = Ferrari))+
  geom_line()+
  xlab("Year")+ 
  ylab("Total Car Sales")
```